# Blazor WASM Debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm having some trouble running my Blazor app in debug mode which gives me this error in browser's console:

> Assertion failed: Cannot call unknown function mono_wasm_set_is_debugger_attached, make sure it is exported

If I try to create a new Blazor WASM app it works but I can't see any difference between the projects...

One thing I notice in the browser is that a new application loads a file:

> dotnet.6.0.15.4de83zsqbd.js

while the old app loads:

> dotnet..13mw2fucg2.js

Any idea where this difference in the .js file might come from?

Tried creating a new app to see the differences but can't find any.

Comment: clean your solution and delete bin and obj from your projects and then try again.

Comment: Tried that, no luck...

Comment: Add some info, send your program.cs, and check where error occurred? In program, layout, razor page or ...? Check project info with double click on the project to check the .net version too.

Comment: There's no error, apart from the one in the browser mentioned in the question, the breakpoints are simply not hit (thery are actually disabled with the error "...current source code is different from the version built into..."
.net versions are the same, nuget packages are the same.

Comment: If it is a asp.net hosted solution delete bin and obj from the client, not the server

Comment: @Santiago I've already deleted all the bin and obj folders from all the projects.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this?

Comment: No...just gave up trying to run in debug mode...